# Adding a constant String to regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

String is : 2013-3-03 14:27:33 [main] INFO  Main - Start

Corresponding regex is :

```
/^(?<time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}) \[(?<thread>.*)\] (?<level>[^\s]+)(?<message>.*)/
```

which produces result

```
"time"    : "2013-3-03 14:27:33",
"thread"  : "main",
"level"   : "INFO",
"message" : "  Main - Start"
```

Editing the actual log file is out of my control hence I want to make changes in regex to add some constant. The output which I want is

```
"time"    : "2013-3-03 14:27:33",
"thread"  : "main",
"level"   : "INFO",
"message" : "  Main - Start",
"app"     : "abc"
```

what I have tried is something like below but is there some better way to acheive my requirement ?

```
/^(?<time>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}) \[(?<thread>.*)\] (?<level>[^\s]+)(?<message>.*)(?<app_abc>)/
```

Comment: You (can't) don't need regex to do that. When regex parses your string and when you create your Key:Value pairs Object - simply add to it whatever is needed. Regex is made to *consume* strings, not to add stuff to it.

Comment: You don:t say anything about what program / environment  you are using this Regex in. If you can use a Regex Replace function instead, you can add your ABC inside your replacestring.

Comment: I am using this regex in FluentD configuration which parses logs generated by SpringBoot Microservice and sends them to Splunk. I don't have control over logs generated by the Microservice app but I need to provide the name of Microservice to Splunk.  I understand regex is for consumption hence I am looking for some hacky solution. I don't have an idea about the Regex Replace function.